# Como aplicar o patch em um arquivo específico?

Tags: git

Gerei um patch do `master` branch e gostaria de aplicá-lo a um branch secundário, mas o erro, acredito, acontece porque foi criado pelo `master` patch de ramificação:

```
error: patch failed: src/projects/file.py:16
error: src/projects/file.py: patch does not apply
```

Tentei resolver assim:

```
git apply --reject --ignore-space-change file.path
```

Algumas partes foram aplicadas enquanto outras ocorreu erro.

Comment: Tentou passar o `--ignore-whitespace` também como argumento no comando? Está aplicando o path no mesmo diretório o qual gerou ele na outra branch? Tente também: `patch -p1 < file.patch`